# Bootstrap collapse move rest of html body

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap and make collapse but every time I click on it rest of body go down/up. Is it possible to don't move rest of body?
    This is my example code:

```
<body>
    <div class="panel-group">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">Panel Body</div>
                <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Collapsible panel</a></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that your parent container's height is auto. So it will basically resize if the child containers are resized.

Set the parent's height. Either programmatically to a fixed height, or you can set it to a % of the page height or whatever.
Below would make it 100% of page height:

```
.panel-group
 {
   height:100vh;
 }
```

Example [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pbdONA)